# How can I convert json string to object in UWP ?

Tags: .net, json, uwp

I get a `HttpContent`that contains a json response

```
string jsoncontent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I found that the class `JavaScriptSerializer` can deserialize the string for me, but this class does not exist in UWP, is there any other class like this in UWP ? 
Is there another alternative to convert JSON to dictionnary ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Simply install it from NuGet (or manually), then do

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var myDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<[your types here]>>(jsoncontent);
```